# Java: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 4

Tags: java, arrays

I always get this Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

```
    Output in = new Output();
    int numbers[] = new int[4];
    numbers[0] = in.inInt("1. Zahl: ");
    numbers[1] = in.inInt("2. Zahl: ");
    numbers[2] = in.inInt("3. Zahl: ");
    numbers[3] = in.inInt("4. Zahl: ");     
    numbers[4] = in.inInt("5. Zahl: ");     
    int max = 0;

    for(int counter = 0; counter < numbers.length; counter++) {
        if (numbers[counter] > max) {
            max = numbers[counter]; 
        }   
    }

    System.out.println("Die größte eingegebene Zahl ist: " + max);
```

Comment: `<`, not `<=`. Surely a dupe.

Comment: Yes, of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Comment: array.length - 1 is the last index of an array. Therefor <= should be changed to <.

Comment: Answered as a community wiki -- no one gets rep credit for this.

Comment: So the error is before actually: you create an array of size 4 but you try to insert 5 elements. See what you did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that valid array indices go from 0 to array-length - 1 since arrays are 0-based. So in your for loop, change `counter <= numbers.length` to `counter < numbers.length`

Now problem

This question already has an answer here:
What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it? 7 answers
I always get this Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

```
Output in = new Output();
int numbers[] = new int[4];
numbers[0] = in.inInt("1. Zahl: ");
numbers[1] = in.inInt("2. Zahl: ");
numbers[2] = in.inInt("3. Zahl: ");
numbers[3] = in.inInt("4. Zahl: ");     
numbers[4] = in.inInt("5. Zahl: ");   // ****** here****
int max = 0;
```

Again, arrays go from 0 to length - 1. You're trying to put something into index at the length position, and that should give you an AIOOB error.

Comment: i still get the same error with this

Comment: @iTzMine: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34711707/edit) (click on the link) and show us your latest code, the code that is still causing the error.

Comment: @iTzMine Then the error is elsewhere. Read carefully the linked question to see what causes this exception.

Comment: @iTzMine: new problem, and you need to re-read my answer, especially the part about arrays going from 0 to length - 1. Your array is size 4 and you're putting **five items into it**.  Better still -- just use an ArrayList.

Comment: I deleted this line: numbers[4].... and now it works. Thank You!